# ¿Cómo crear un array de números dentro de un bucle dependiendo de el valor introducido?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando aprender PHP pero me he atascado. El caso es que estoy haciendo una función donde se pueda guardar en un array un número que se introduzca de 1 a 10. Luego, tengo que mostrarlo de forma descendente, pero no lo logro. No sé si tiene que ver con los ámbitos de las variables. ¿Se puede usar una variable que declare antes de bucle, en el bucle? Intento esto:

```
<?php
    $numeros = array();

    $valor = 5;

    while (valor >= 0) {
        $numeros [] = $valor;
        $valor --;  
    }
?>
```

¿Alguna pista? Gracias.

Comment: No tienes ninguna instrucción de impresión como echo, puede que por eso no muestra nada

Comment: Aunque le ponga un echo, tampoco hace nada. Es un bucle infinito en el navegador. La cuestión es lograr que si elijo por ejemplo el número 5, imprima 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- Tu código esta *completo* pero carece una de instrucción que imprima los valores, por lo tanto procesará la resta por cada iteración pero no te *dirá nada al respecto*
- Puedes tomar la misma operación de decremento que ya existe e imprimirla
- Como la variable `$valor` que inicia en 5 pierde en su valor 1 por cada iteración hecha, esta es la que te entrega el resultado planeado y que podemos imprimir
- Al momento y con base en lo que expones en la pregunta y los comentarios, el vector que declaras no tiene nada que hacer en tu ejercicio

Código:

```
$limite = 5;

while ($limite >= 0) {
    echo $limite--.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Salida:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

**Lectura de interés**

- [Estructura y funcionamiento del ciclo **`while`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php)